# Failure to Configure New Farm (Keyset does not exist)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, server-farm, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to set up a SharePoint Foundation 2010 farm on my local Windows 10 machine in order to make a dev copy of our production site.  I have SQL Server 2012 installed, and I point the configuration utility at the localhost instance.  During step 3 of the install, it fails citing the following error:

> Failed to create the confuguration database.
>
> An exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was thrown. Additional exception information: Keyset does not exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090016)

I have looked around at possible solutions, and the only real one I found that I can understand is to set the permissions on one of my local folders.  That hasn't helped.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: If you're going to down vote this question, please offer feedback or try to answer the question.  People use this forum for help and guidance, and drive-by down voting with no explanation offers neither.

Comment: Why not setup a virtual machine on windows 10?

Comment: Because the organization I'm working for doesn't have VMWare.

Comment: What hyper v which windows product

Comment: As I said in the OP, Windows 10.  And, what is a Hyper V?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/windows_welcome?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Oh, it's a VM Engine.  I can see how difficult that would have been to type as a response.  I'm not sure how a VM is gonna help me here... but... I guess that's good to know about.

Comment: Besides... won't I have to use up another OS license for this?  I can't just use up my company's license to build a VM without justification as to why I need to set one up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cryptographic error. You will need to set permissions on a the crypto keys folder:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/servergeeks/archive/2014/07/10/keyset-does-not-exist-error.aspx

The folder is located at:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
```

OR

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
```

Alternatively, go into computer certificates and grant access to a specific certificate.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue.  I granted Everyone Full Access to that folder and I still get the same error.  Granted, when I tried to apply the new permission, I got an error on one of the files saying "Failed to enumerate objects in the container.  Access is denied."

Comment: UPDATE: While performing the step mentioned above, I was getting an error saying "Failed to enumerate objects in the container.  Access is denied."  I then found this, which allowed me to finally finish creation of my Farm:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/permission-error-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in/93ea883f-853f-4981-a697-928bfbc71642?page=1&auth=1